# Why are there no "deRabanan regulations" on the Ben Sorer uMoreh Mitzvah?

Tags: halacha-theory, children-parenting, derabanan

This is the first question in a series on Ben SU"M.
Let me recap on this Mitzvah ([Rambam Mamrim 7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Rebels.7?vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi)):

1. A 13 to 13 and 3 months old boy that disobeys his father and mother in a very specific way of
2. Stealing his dad's money, buying a large amount of meat and wine with it and consuming it in "half-done" in a company of bad guys.
3. The parents take the kid to a 3-judges court first and have the boy beaten.
4. The boy continues and it escalates quickly to the court of 23, which gets him stoned.

All the Meforshim explain how bad this behavior is, so bad all Israel has to see him executed and take notes.

Usually, for every capital sin (think Shabbos), we have tons of deRabanan rulings that prevent others to get close to transgressing. However, there are no deRabanan regulations here whatsoever to potentially prevent this situation.

For example:

1. Measures to prevent disobeying parents before age of 13.
2. Special measures for a child that steals money from his parents.
3. Prohibition to eat meat half-done.
4. Prohibition of hanging out with bad friends.

Why there's no D"R regulation and even no mentioning **that "שמא יבוא לידי בן סו"מ"**?

Comment: If you hold לא היה ולא נברא then there would be no need for any rabbinic precautions

Comment: Aren't there rabbinic prohibitions on stealing? Why don't those help prevent this too?

Comment: @JoelK If so nobody would care to explain the reason for stoning - there's nothing wrong with this behavior just גזירת הכתוב. Also for the second opinion?

Comment: @DoubleAA Stealing only pays back - no stoning. And there are tons of Halochos for stealing.

Comment: @alberko what's your point? The derabanans work to prevent both. Your premise is just false. There are derabanans to prevent ben sorer umore

Comment: The Torah already included a ready made D'rabbanan (fence against coming to be a real BSUM) by having the boy merely whipped the 1st time.

Comment: Also "The Rabbis did not decree about something that is considered unusual." milsa d'lo sh'echichah, lo gazru bey Rabbanan.

Comment: What would you like? Something along the lines of, "A 13.1 year old boy who steals a large amount of money from his father and is forewarned is forbidden to purchase meat, firewood, or charcoal"?

Comment: Please source _Two witnesses see the whole story_ - don't recall seeing that anywhere.

Comment: @DannySchoemann כֵּיצַד דָּנִין בֵּן סוֹרֵר וּמוֹרֶה. מְבִיאִין אוֹתוֹ אָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ תְּחִלָּה לְבֵית דִּין שֶׁל שְׁלֹשָׁה וְאוֹמְרִין לָהֶן בְּנֵנוּ זֶה סוֹרֵר וּמוֹרֶה. וּמְבִיאִין שְׁנֵי עֵדִים שֶׁגָּנַב מִשֶּׁל אָבִיו וְקָנָה בָּשָׂר וְיַיִן בְּמַה שֶּׁגָּנַב וְאָכַל אוֹתָהּ אֲכִילָה הָאֲמוּרָה אַחַר הַהַתְרָאָה.

Comment: @AlBerko - Where's that from? it's not a Mishna.

Comment: @DannySchoemann the link I put in Rambam's Hilchot Mamrim

Comment: @JoshK I added examples.

Comment: @DavidKenner A good point, but all the sub-behaviors are very common. The only uncommon thing is for the parents to  incriminate their son. I added possible examples of prohibitions of regulations.

Comment: @AlBerko since the combination of all those things is uncommon; and its only the combination that can make him a BSUM, we don't make gezerahs.

Comment: @DavidKenner You have an answer in your comment. I was about to post it and then saw you did.

Comment: @LN6595 Go ahead and answer what you like. I do not have time to write one in my style now. :) I only had time for a comment.

Answer (score 4):

מלתא דלא שכיח ליה לא גזרו ביה רבנן - the Rabbis only initiated decrees on things which are common.

The Ben Sorer uMorer is an uncommon scenario (perhaps an impossible scenario), and therefore there are no decrees regarding it.

The Rabbis did enact decrees regarding the more common scenario of a child struggling to respect his parents. Hence, they decreed that one may not sit in his parent's chair, etc.

*with thanks to David Kenner

Comment: Fine idea. Seems true

Comment: They didn’t decree that a child may not sit in his parent’s chair. That’s a d’Oraisa of איש אמו ואביו תיראו, not a d’Rabbanan. It’s their explanation of the passuk, sure, but that’s an important distinction.

Comment: gotta +1 that :)